# Ember: Does ember-model allow binding computed values using .properties(...)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-model

I'm trying to get a computed value in my model to update using the .property('key') syntax. My model is like:

```
App.Camera = Em.Model.extend({
    id: attr(),
    uid: attr(),
    name: attr(),
    type: attr(),
    refresh: attr(),

    thumbnailUrl384x216: function() {
        return '%@/devices/%@/thumbnail?width=384&height=216'.fmt(apiBaseUri, this.get('uid'));
    }.property('uid', 'refresh'),

    thumbnailUrlFull: function() {
        return '%@/devices/%@/thumbnail?width=1280&height=720'.fmt(apiBaseUri, this.get('uid'));
    }.property('uid', 'refresh')
});
```

In my camera route I am modifying the refresh variable on an interval, but it is not causing the thumbnailUrl's to update.  Am I doing something wrong or does [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) not support the .property() feature.

I'm able to use the refresh attribute in my template and I see it updating.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ember-Model uses Ember's object model, so it definitely supports computed properties. Are you sure that the value itself isn't updating? Maybe the value is but your template isn't. Try a `console.log` in one of the properties statement to see if you get anything.

Comment: It's working, since I wasn't  using the updated value and the result of the computed value was not changing it threw me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computed value was not updating because I wasn't using the changing refresh value in the computation. Adding that fixed it.